# UIWindow animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I currently use a custom UIWindow to display a custom alert view to make it look Apple style. When I remove it, it doesn't fade automatically, sk I decided to use a UIView animation and change the alpha to 0 then remove it but that still didn't do the trick. Would you guys know what to do?

Comment: This should work... please post the code you are using to make the animation

Answer (score 9):

For the faded background window used by my own custom AlertView class (similar to what it sounds like you are doing) I made a custom UIWindow and overrode makeKeyAndVisible, but you can also do this outside context of the class:

```
- (void)makeKeyAndVisible
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.alpha = 0;

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"fade-in" context: nil];

    [super makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)resignKeyWindow
{
    self.alpha = 1;

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"fade-out" context: nil];

    [super resignKeyWindow];

    self.alpha = 0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

greyWindow.alpha = 0;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't solve the problem, stuck with teh same problem